# React Memo Feature gives :- Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have functional component below:-

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'
const DropDownMenu= (props)=> {

const options = [
    { key: 'fruits', text: 'fruits', value: 'Fruits' },
    { key: 'vegetables', text: 'vegetables', value: 'Vegetables' },
    { key: 'home-cooked', text: 'home-cooked', value: 'Home-Cooked' },
    { key: 'green-waste', text: 'green-waste', value: 'Green-Waste' },
    { key: 'other', text: 'other', value: 'other' },

];

function onChangeHandler(e) {
  console.log(e.target.innerText);
  props.getCategoryValue(e.target.innerText);
};

return (
        <Dropdown placeholder='Category' fluid selection options={options} 
 onChange={onChangeHandler} />
    );

};

export default React.memo(DropDownMenu);
```

Above functional component is being rendered in its parent component sellForm.js as below:-

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import { Button, Form} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import AutoCompleteInput from '../GoogleAutocomplete/autoComplete';
import DropDownMenu from '../DropDown/DropDown';
import update from 'react-addons-update';
import './sellForm.css';
import PreviewImages from '../PreviewImage/previewUploadedImages';
import FileInput from '../FileInput/FileInput';

class sellForm extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    //this.imageUpload = React.createRef();
    this.state={
        postID: '',
        title: '',
        description:'',
        category:'',
        price: '',
        amount: '',
        freshness: '',
        contact: '',
        location: '',
        timestamp: '',
        images: []
    }
}

getCategoryValue=(category)=>{
    this.setState({category: category})
};

getItemLocation=(locationObject)=>{
    this.setState({location: locationObject})
};

saveInfo=(e)=>{
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]:e.target.value});
};

postButtonClickHandler=()=>{
    console.log(this.state)
    console.log(typeof (this.state.images[0].file))
    // send this info to firebase database
};

 handleImageUpload= (file)=>{
     console.log('handle image Upload in sell form');
     this.setState({
         images: update(this.state.images, {$push: [file]})
     })

 };

 handleImageDeletion=(indexOfImage)=>{
     console.log('handle image deletion in sell form - index to be deleted is : ' ,indexOfImage);
     this.setState((prevState)=>{
         return{
             // images: prevState.images.splice(indexOfImage,1)
             images: update(this.state.images, {$splice: [[indexOfImage,1]]})
         }
     })
 };

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState){
    console.log('[sellform.js] shouldComponentUpdate');
    return true;
}

componentDidMount(){
    console.log('[sellform.js] componentDidMount');
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
    //when user uploads or deletes images, then props changes
    //this lifecycle executes when function gets new props before render()
    //only use when component's inner state depends upon props...
    console.log('[sellform.js] getDerivedStateFromProps')
    return null;
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    console.log('[sellform.js] componentDidUpdate')
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    console.log('[sellform.js] componentWillUmMount')
}

render(){
    console.log('render of sellForm');
    console.log(this.state.images);

    let previewImages = (<PreviewImages deleteUploadedImage={this.handleImageDeletion} images={this.state.images}/>)

    return(
        <Form>
            <Form.Field>
                <DropDownMenu getCategoryValue={this.getCategoryValue}/>
            </Form.Field>

            <Form.Field>
                {<AutoCompleteInput
                    onChange={()=>{}}
                    onPlaceSelected={this.getItemLocation}/>}
            </Form.Field>

            <Form.Field>
                <input
                    placeholder='What are you selling ?'
                    name="title"
                    onChange={this.saveInfo}/>
            </Form.Field>

            <Form.Field>
                <input
                    placeholder='Price'
                    name="price"
                    onChange={this.saveInfo} />
            </Form.Field>

            <Form.Field>
                    <FileInput appendImageToArray={this.handleImageUpload}/>
            </Form.Field>

            <Form.Field>
                <Button
                    type='submit'
                    onClick={this.postButtonClickHandler}>Post
                </Button>

            </Form.Field>

            <Form.Field>
                <div className='previewImageContainer'>
                    {previewImages}
                </div>
            </Form.Field>

        </Form>
    )
}
}



export default sellForm
```

---

when sellFom renders it gives following error:-
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `sellForm`.
    at invariant (react-dom.development.js:57)

Any ideas react community ??

Comment: can it be this line? `{<AutoCompleteInput
                    onChange={()=>{}}
                    onPlaceSelected={this.getItemLocation}/>}` try removing curly brackets

Comment: Can you try and comment the memo comment in your SellForm and check. Commenting components one by one will help you in identifying the exact cause

Comment: @SaidKholov.... onChange={()=>{}} ....here i am passing only empty function.. i checked it is not issue...

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri... i tried commenting,,,, if i comment  <DropDown /> in render method of SellForm... it works ..... no issue... with <DropDown /> in render method of  SellForm gives same error,,,,,

Comment: Which version of React are you using, Can you make sure you have 16.6.0 or higher version of react and react-dom

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri,,,,, yes i made update to react and react-dom to 16.6.0.....                           
     "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "react-firebaseui": "^3.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",

Comment: okay one last thing, can you check without exporting the functional component using React.memo

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri... i did not get ur point without exporting the functional component ... can u please more clarify ???

Comment: What I meant to say is try just `export default DropDownMenu;`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri.... it works then completely fine.....

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox or something, I am not able to reproduce your issue

Comment: here is my code for above project at this repo...  if this helps ...... https://github.com/manpreetsjsu/cmpe133project/tree/manpreet

Comment: i created sandbox and found that it is working fine in sandbox,,,https://codesandbox.io/s/o9ny76x4q6

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri..it worked ... it was issue with version,,,, thanks so mch

Comment: @ManpreetSingh What was the exact issue? Version of what? Where does the `Form` component come from?

Comment: @Vernon ..when i updated the react and react-dom version , somehow those changes did not apply immediately... idk y... so when i tried wrapping funct. component with memo,, it gave error.... Form is semantic UI component  . let me know if this clarifies your question....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this issue by updating both `react` and `react-dom` to **16.6.0**.

Comment: i think ,,, this is issue with version,, but i updated using                      
  `npm install --save react@^16.6.0 react-dom@^16.6.0` ... it is messing up in localhost... when i created sandbox for sharing,, it is working fine...

Comment: it finally worked ... it is issue with version update

Comment: update react and dom version its worked fine bcoz its introduce in react@16.6.0

Comment: Great find! Updating only react version is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think problem is due to naming od sellForm. Ax far as know, React accepts CamelCase Name for classes. Take this example for now:

```js
function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Tes</p>
    </div>
  );
}
const MemoizedExample = React.memo(Example)
function exampleParent() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Parent</p>
       <MemoizedExample />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<exampleParent />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

In above I have made name as smallcase for class, see the rendering doesn't happen.
If you change the name of component from exampleComponent to ExampleComponent It will work. Similiarly for your problem change your class name from sellFrom to SellForm :). Here is the working one with component name camelcase:

```js
function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Tes</p>
    </div>
  );
}
const MemoizedExample = React.memo(Example)
function ExampleParent() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Parent</p>
       <MemoizedExample />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ExampleParent />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: As you suggested , i made change to SellForm,,, but this did not help.... i am actually already following CamelCasing when i render SellForm in parent Component SellModal as below:
import SellForm from './sellForm'                                                                                                     https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057702/10578052

Comment: I mean try to change the name of sellForm component to SellForm component. Look this is very simple implementation of React.memo. It's very hard for me to see any other error in this. Check the code snippet attached in answer carefully.

Comment: @simbathesailor....i made sure that I am using CamelCase convention.... but the error still persists.... it should be very straight forward implementation according React docs.. but Idk y its not working for me....

Comment: I believe here is nothing wrong with sellForm itself since error happens inside of its `render()`

Comment: @skyboyer, Yeah you may be right. Need more info, here I think. Something other is screwing it up. Can't conclude as if now. :)

Comment: @skyboyer,@simbathesailor... if i remove React.memo wrapping around my functional component .. it works completely fine...  do u think the parent components affect React.memo somehow ...that cud be issue.. any ideas ??..here is link to my github repo for full react code... https://github.com/manpreetsjsu/cmpe133project/tree/manpreet